# Difference between ClassPath and SourcePath in Project SDKs under Platform Settings in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using `Intellij IDEA 2019.3` and when I add a new `Java` library (.jar files) to my project, in order to access library implementation (`.java` file instead of `.class` file), I have to add all necessary .jar file into `ClassPath` tab and .zip file into `Sourcepath`. It's working and I don't know exactly why it does. Is there any explanation?

Another question: What's `Platform Settings`? Why does it have such a name?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Platform settings* is responsible for so called "global" settings in your intellij IDEA. Adding java libraries under class/source path let all yours projects access to these libraries.

As for difference between classpath and sourcepath.. You actually answer your question. In order to access class files (`.class`) you need jar file to be added to classpath. In order to access actual implementation (`.java`), say for debugging purpose, you have to add it to sourcepath.

See more [Define an SDK in Intellij IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#)

It's better to add `.jar` to project settings not to platform. You could add specific libraries in `Project structure -> Libraries` tab

[image]

See [Libraries and Global Libraries](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/libraries-and-global-libraries.html)

Then if you want to navigate to `.java` file you could open corresponding `.class` file and add source file using one of options in upper right corner:

[image]

After that you will see Classes file and Sources file in Libraries tab:

[image]

Comment: add `.jar` file to Libraries tab don't let me be able to navigate to the `.java` file source code (it's navigate to decompiled `.class` file too)